# How to prove $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{199}-\frac1{200}=\frac1{101}+\frac1{102}+\ldots+\frac1{200}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I want to prove $$1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{199}-\frac1{200}=\frac1{101}+\frac1{102}+\ldots+\frac1{200}$$
First I added $\frac12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{200}$ to both sides of the equation but that wasn't helpful.
I'm not sure how to prove it I can write it as partial sums:$$\sum_{n=1}^{200}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n=\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n+100}$$But I don't see a way to proceed from here.

Comment: Instead of adding $\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{200}$ try subtracting $\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{103}+...+\frac{1}{199}$ from both sides of the equation to get cancellation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{200} =\frac12\left(1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1{100}\right)$$

and you may want to add it twice to both sides

Comment: This is beautiful;) thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, this together with a series expansion of the Harmonic numbers, suggests each of the original sums (in fact about $0.6906534$) can be approximated by $\log_e(2)-\frac{1}{400}\approx 0.6906472$